# How to turn off some bits while ignoring others using only bitwise operators

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I've searched for this, but my results were unsatisfactory, probably because of how hard it is to word. I have one object, `state`, which is a `byte` that represents which parts of my object are to be rendered when observed, and a method, `disableParts(byte partsToDisable)`, which will turn off all bits in `state` that are ON in `partsToDisable`. **How do I achieve this functionality in bitwise operations?** (that is, only using `AND`, `OR`, `XOR`, `NOT`, `LSHIFT`, `ARSHIFT`, `LRSHIFT`, `PLUS`, `MINUS`, `MULTIPLY`, and/or `DIVIDE` and basic program functions such as loops and branching statements)

For a bit of clarity, here is a visual representation of my desired functionality:

```
  0010 0101 (current state, 37 in this example)
? 1010 0010 (bits to disable, -94 in this example)
============
  0000 0101 (new state, 5 in this example)
```

and a dummy class (in Java because that's how I think, but the solution can be any language or pseudo-code):

```java
class BitThoughts
{
  byte state;
  
  public void doIt()
  {
    state = 0b00100101;
    System.out.println("Initial state: " + state);

    disableParts(0b10100010);

    if (state == 0b00000101)
      System.out.println("Success! New state is " + state);
    else
      System.out.println("Failure! New state is " + state);
  }

  public void disableParts(byte partsToDisable)
  {
    //Do magic to state
  }
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask#Masking_bits_to_0.

Comment: ... wait... derp... are you saying it's a simple NAND? *facepalm*

Comment: The answer ought to be moved out of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the poke, @PeterMortensen! I did that back when it wasn't as clear to me whether that was what should be done. I've removed it!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to invert the bits (bit-wise NOT) in `partsToDisable`, so you end up with a mask where the 1's are the bits to be left alone and the 0's are the bits to be turned off.  Then AND this mask with the state value.

```
public void disableParts( byte partsToDisable)
{
    state = state & (~partsToDisable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just invert the bits of the parts, you can just AND it with the state

```
 void disableParts(byte parts) {
     byte invertOfParts = 0b11111111 - parts;
     state &= invertOfParts
 }
```

Comment: But relying on a particular compiler extension to work? Near "0b11111111". What are the requirements for this to work? What was it tested on?