# How to simplify this "clear multiple bits at once" function?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I finally figured out through trial and error how to clear multiple bits on an integer:

```
const getNumberOfBitsInUint8 = function(i8) {
  let i = 0
  while (i8) {
    i++
    i8 >>= 1
  }
  return i
}

const write = function(n, i, x) {
  let o = 0xff // 0b11111111
  let c = getNumberOfBitsInUint8(x)
  let j = 8 - i // right side start
  let k = j - c // right side remaining
  let h = c + i
  let a = x << k // set bits
  let b = a ^ o // set bits flip
  let d = o >> h // mask right
  let q = d ^ b //
  let m = o >> j // mask left
  let s = m << j
  let t = s ^ q // clear bits!
  let w = n | a // set the set bits
  let z = w & ~t // perform some magic https://stackoverflow.com/q/8965521/169992
  return z
}
```

The `write` function takes an integer `n`, the index `i` to write bits into, and the bits value `x`.

Is there any way to simplify this function down and remove some steps? (Without just combining multiple operations on a single line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to first clear the relevant part and then copy the bits into it:

```
return (n & ~((0xff << (8 - c)) >> i)) | (x << (8 - c - i))
```

assuming the left shift is restricted to 8 bits so the top bits disappear. Another is to use xor to find the bits to be changed :

```
return n ^ ((((n >> (8 - c - i)) ^ x) << (8 - c)) >> i)
```